# R: how to share a label name in a boxplot?

Tags: r, label, boxplot

I made the following graph [image]

with the command

```
boxplot(tstats,names=c(expression(bar(x)),"","med(x)","","mad(x)","",
         var(x)","",expression(q[.75]-q[.25]),""),
         col=rep(c("wheat","chocolate"),5))
abline(h=2,col="steelblue",lty=2)
abline(h=-2,col="steelblue",lty=2)
title(main="normal data")
```

but I would like instead to center the shared names between the two (wheat and chocolate) boxes. How do I modify the first axis labels?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should do what you want:

```
##Some dummy data
dd = data.frame(values = rnorm(40), type=LETTERS[1:4])

##Don't plot the axes labels
##but add in the "plot frame"
boxplot(dd$values ~ dd$type, axes=FALSE, 
                  frame.plot=TRUE, ylim=c(-4, 4))

##Now add in the y-axis
axis(2, seq(-4,4,by=2))
##Add in the x-axis at points: 1.5 and 3.5
axis(1, c(1.5,3.5), c("Med", "Mad"))
```